# Getting NZEC error in SPOJ with Java for this Code

Tags: java

This is my answer for half of half question in SPOJ( Question ID :12156) . I'm a beginner in JAVA. Please Help why am i getting an error. I'm able to get an expected answer while compiling in Ideone. Thanks

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] name= new String[10];
        int size,count;
        String temp,news;
        char[] chars= new char[20];

        temp=scan.nextLine();
        count=Integer.parseInt(temp);

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                name[i]=scan.nextLine();
            }

                for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
                {
                    news=name[j];
                    size=news.length();
                    chars=news.toCharArray();
                        for(int k=0;k<size/2;k=k+2)
                            {
                                System.out.print(chars[k]);
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information: what is the exception you receive (include the stacktrace). Also we have no idea what _"SPOJ( Question ID :12156)"_ is. Describe what the program is supposed to do. It is your job to make it easy for others to answer your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : This is the question http://www.spoj.com/problems/STRHH/

The site only throws 'Runtime error ( NZEC)'
There are no stack trace and error details available.  I know this is difficult with no error description, Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It would also be helpful if you'd define your acronyms if they're not widely known. What is SPOJ? What is NZEC?

Comment: @MikeHarris, SPOJ (Sphere Online Judge) is an online judge system, commonly used to train for programming contests. NZEC is a status that indicates that a specific code submission resulted in a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the following points in the problem description:

> In the first line of input your are given the positive integer t
>   (1 <= t <= 100) - the number of test cases.

In your code, you can handle 10 (and not 100) strings at maximum.

`String[] name = new String[10];`

> In the each of the next t lines, you are given a sequence of 2*k
>   (1 <= k <= 100) characters.

In your code, you can handle 20 (and not 200) characters at maximum.

`char[] chars = new char[20];`

Answer (score 0):

I did attempt same question half of half at SPOJ, my code is accepted.
I think array initialisation should be based on input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCase = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        String[] inputStringArray = new String[testCase];
        for (int x = 0; x < testCase; x++) {
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            inputStringArray[x]=input;
            System.out.println("#-"+x);
        }
        for(int y=0;y<testCase;y++){
            String text = inputStringArray[y];
            char[] inputArray = text.toCharArray();
            int len = inputArray.length/2;
            for(int z=0;z<len;z=z+2){
                System.out.print(inputArray[z]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```